# Usage of 吗 vs 嘛 in Informal Questions

Tags: usage

A friend wanted to know what I was doing so sent a message with this question: 你在干吗呢, then immediately corrected herself by typing: 你在干嘛呢. I found it interesting that Google translate seems to do a better job translating the first sentence.

What are the differences in actual meaning between these sentences? Is there enough of a difference that a correction is needed?

I've looked at some related questions such as [Connotation of 吗 questions vs. affirmative/negative questions](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1750/in-what-instances-can-use-you-use-%E5%B9%B2%E5%98%9B-over-%E5%B9%B2%E5%90%97-and-vice-versa), which has helped some, but I'm still not sure in this case.